# dividing listbox items into two parts and pasting them into two listbox

Tags: vb.net

so the code i ma trying to run is:

```
 Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim size2 As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count / 2
        Dim size1 As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - size2

        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.GetRange(0, size1))
        ListBox3.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.GetRange(size1, size2))
    End Sub
```

i have imported System.Linq but error occers getrange is not a member of listbox.objectcollection

Comment: Ask yourself two questions. 1) Why are you using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event? This code will be executed each time you select an item in ListBox1, is that what you want? 2) what if the number of items is odd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a `GetRange()` extension in Linq. The [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) class has [**such a method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx), however. So you could use the [**`Cast(Of TResult)` extension**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the collection into an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, then use the [**`ToList()` extension**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert that into a `List(Of T)`:

```
Dim ItemsList As List(Of Object) = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).ToList()

ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ItemsList.GetRange(0, size1))
ListBox3.Items.AddRange(ItemsList.GetRange(size1, size2))
```